# Bluemix Cloud Foundry App with custom domain uses bluemix certificate

Tags: ssl, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, client-certificates

I have a Node JS Cloud Foundry app deployed to IBM Bluemix (IBM Cloud) and I am using my own personal domain for it. Using letsencrypt to create a certificate, I have provided Bluemix the ssl certificate for my domain which covers the DNS name of my domain, and also the subdomain www.

I have configured the DNS for my domain to use:

- A NAME record for `@` pointing to `5.10.124.142`
- C NAME record for `www` pointing to `secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net`.

The problem is when I navigate to `https://www.example.com` the site shows and uses my custom certificate. But when I navigate to `https://example.com` I see a certificate mis-match error:

> This server could not prove that it is example.com; its security certificate is from *.eu-gb.mybluemix.net. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is the A Name record.
Let me share a link with you so that you can be up to date with the procedure to follow for custom domains.
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/secapps.html#securingapps

I think the best soultion is to create another CNAME Record  for the example.com URL pointing at the secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net 
In the docs, as far as I could see, there is no mention of A record for DNS. 
Let me know if you solve this issue I can give you more help if needed.

Comment: Yes this worked. I had a bit of a problem with my DNS provider getting this configured but yes, using only CNAME records worked very well. Thank you

Comment: can you provide an example of how you fixed this? @AndrewJamesDaniel, I mean, what records where the right in your DNS config. or example of DNS config.

Comment: The interface to configure the DNS of my host may differ to yours but my config is as follows:

@ | CNAME | secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net
example.com | CNAME | secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net
www | CNAME | secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net